# User profile disks still active after removing roles

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, rdp, user-profile

I wanted to try out all the remote desktop roles on my server, so I did a hyper-v install of Windows Server 2012 R2 datacenter on my server which also runs Windows Server 2012 R2 datacenter. However I didn't notice I still was connected to my base OS installation, not the VM when I installed the roles.

So basically I installed all of the remote desktop roles except licensing and configured them. Once I realized my mistake I uninstalled all of the roles and now I'm still stuck with user profile disks.

I can't disable UDP trough PowerShell since I have no collection available. I have also tried to install all the roles again to try and disable UDP but it seems that it won't install properly now for some reason.

Is there any way to revert back to regular user profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Get-WmiObject -NameSpace root\CIMV2\TerminalServices -Class Win32_TSSessionDirectory).DisableUserVhd()
```

Worked for me. However now administrator are directed to c:\users\TEMP instead of c:\users\username the other accounts works as intended

so now i got that problem instead :)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how i clone a RDS server with User Profile Disk.**
I cloned the Windows 2016 RDS Hyper-V VM.
Shutdown the VM with RDS.
Copy the drive (.vhdx )
Create a new VM with the copied vhdx.
Disable network to the old domain.
Rename computer and change to workgroup.
Sysprep with "generel".
Start the new server and prepare it for first use.

The local administrator profile was pointing to UPD, so tried to uninstall Remote Desktop service.
Server is still using UPD.

**From UPD to local profiles**

- I deleted this Registry folder:
     "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal
     Server\ClusterSettings"
   Created a new user with administrator
     rights.
   Used this user to delete 
     "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\ProfileList"
     with .bak extensions.
   Restart and now local users can create
     profiles in c:\users folder.

Connect to Domain as the a new member server.
Installed Remote Desktop and add the server to Remote Desktop Collection.
I have now an exstra RDS server in the collection or to be used for other things.

I'm not sure if it was nessesary to uninstall Remote Desktop, I will give it a try without next time.